# Browserify - order of transforms/plugins

Tags: javascript, browserify

In browserify, can you explicitly set the order in which transforms and plugins run? If so, how do you do it in package.json config and in the browserify API?

Specifically, I'd like to use [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify) and [tsify](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify) together and to that end, `aliasify` has to run first.  How would you go about doing this?

If it isn't possible, how is the order determined?

Comment: Please refer to browserify [handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many information In that [browserify-handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook)

This screenshot is one of them you find.

[image]

--- I added a answer below for a question in comment.

@VladimirRovensky, the plugins are registered to the browserify instance directly, so there is register order.

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify();
b.plugin( firstPlugin, firstPluginOpts );
b.plugin( secondPlugin, secondPluginOpts );
```

after that, each plugin operate as their defined, by listening for events or splicing transforms into the pipeline.

It is hard to understand plugin's order as with transform's order.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, does the same hold for the plugins? In particular, I was interested in whether it's possible to make a transform run before/after a plugin runs.

Comment: @VladimirRovensky, I have added a answer. Hope that helps!